# why singletone class value is nil?

Tags: swift, swift3

In my code something strange happening I couldn't understand why.

Print result is always nil

Here is what I did it is very simple

```
ConditionHolder.instance.condition?.type = ConditionType.fixed
ConditionHolder.instance.condition?. ifoDateAndTime = dateTime
print("conditonvc1=\(ConditionHolder.instance.condition?.type)")
print("conditonvc2=\(ConditionHolder.instance.condition?.ifoDateAndTime?)")
```

and here's my class

```
class ConditionHolder {

   static let instance = ConditionHolder()

    var condition: Condition?
}
```

And Condition class

```
class Condition {

    var ifoDateAndTime: IFODateTime?
    var period: Period?
    var type: String?
}
```

Comment: `var condition` is declared but not initialized. Use a non-optional then the compiler will remind you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `condition` property like this:

```
class ConditionHolder {

    static let instance = ConditionHolder()   
    let condition = Condition()

}
```

or this:

```
class ConditionHolder {

    static let instance = ConditionHolder()

    let condition: Condition

    init() {
        self.condition = Condition()
    }

}
```

Comment: In your second option, `condition` does not need to be optional.